# Creating a Site Using Eclipse Maven Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I would like to create a 'site' containing test reports for my Maven Java project. However, all the online resources that I found were talking about the command 'mvn site'. I do work on Windows, though, therefore I would like to avoid any interaction with its console.

Can I do it using solely the Eclipse Maven Plugin? If I want to tell Maven to build my project, I can right-click it and then choose 'Run As' 'Maven Install'. Is there something similar for generating sites?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the hate for specifically the Windows command prompt? What has it done to you to deserve a cold shoulder?

In any case and more seriously: Eclipse allows you to define run configurations yourself. run -> run configurations. Under "maven build" you can add a new configuration to do a mvn site. This page gives an idea by demonstrating how to do a clean install:

http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html